# $\Delta_g f = 0$ on the Riemannian Manifold $(\mathbb{R}^3 \setminus B , g)$ with conditions on boundary and at infinity

Tags: partial-differential-equations, asymptotics, riemannian-geometry

Consider the manifold $M = \mathbb{R}^3 \setminus B$ where $B$ is the ball with radius $1$ with riemannian metric $g$ (not necessarily the euclidean metric).

I am looking for solutions to $\Delta_g f = 0$ where $f \to 1 $ at infinity and $f=f_0$ on $\partial M$ where $f_0$ is some positive function on $\partial M$

What can we say about existence and uniqueness of this PDE? Any simple proofs?

What can we say about the asymptotic behaviour of $f$ at infinity?

I think if g is the euclidean metric, the asymptotics are:
$$f = 1 + \frac{C}r + O(\frac{1}{r^2}) $$
where $C$ is some constant and $r = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2 + z^2}$ in cartesian coordinates.

What if $g$ is asymptotically flat? (so in cartesian coordinates, the metric satisfies $g_{ij} = \delta_{ij} + O \left(\frac{1}{r^{\delta}}\right) $ for some $\delta > 0 $).

Any help is appreciated. If you know any references, please share it with me.

Comment: Existence & uniqueness: Let $u_k$ be the solution to $\Delta u_k=0$ on $B_k(0)-B_1(0)$, with boundary condition $u_k=f_0$ on $\partial B_1(0)$ and $u_k=1$ on $\partial B_k(0)$. Then let $k\to\infty$, we can find a subsequence of $u_k$ that converges to a limit $f$.

In fact, we can take a large $C$, so that for all $k$ we have $1-\frac{C}{|x|}\leq u_k\leq 1+\frac{C}{|x|}$ on $\partial B_1(0)\cup\partial B_k(0)$, thus by the maximum principle $1-\frac{C}{|x|}\leq u_k\leq 1+\frac{C}{|x|}$. Thus $u_k$ are uniformly bounded and we use interior gradient estimate to get subsequence convergent...

Comment: @YuDing Thank you (again) for your comment. 
1) is this for the euclidean case?
2) How do you know there exists a solution on $B_{k} \setminus B_1$ with those boundary conditions. 
3) How do you know you can find such a C? 
4) can you tell me details about the gradient estimates and how it shows there is a converging subsequence?
Please send me references if you can. Thank you again.

Comment: 1. It should work on manifolds under certain assumptions, but I am not immediately sure what assumptions. 2. See e.g. Theorem 8.14 in Gilbartg-Trudinger [GT].  3. You can let $C$ be $\sup |f_0|$; so the inequality works on boundary, then by maximum principle it works also on the interior. 4. For Euclidean case, the interior gradient estimate can be found in [GT] p 22. Some efforts are needed at the boundary, see e.g. [GT] Theorem 8.13. On manifolds, you can use the Cheng-Yau gradient estimate, and with things like asym. flat, I think it should be possible to handle also the boundary.